# Why do I need to set my PHP timezone when it's already set in WordPress?

Tags: date-time, timezones

I have WordPress set to Los Angles time in Settings > General. In my database I have a DATETIME column. When I use `$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $value_from_db);` and then `$dt->format('n/j/y @ g:iA T');` it displays the timezone as "UTC". In functions.php if I add `date_default_timezone_set( get_option('timezone_string') );` then $dt will output correctly with "PST".

It works, but I didn't think I needed to explicitly set the timezone since I already set it in WordPress. Am I doing something wrong or is this the correct way to set the timezone for my PHP?

Comment: Actually, you could pass a `DateTimeZone` instance as the 3rd parameter to `DateTime::createFromFormat()`, e.g. `DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $value_from_db, new DateTimeZone( 'America/Los_Angeles' ) )`, but in WordPress you should use `date_i18n()` or `wp_date()` (the latter also accepts a custom `DateTimeZone` instance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In functions.php if I add `date_default_timezone_set( get_option('timezone_string') );` then $dt will output correctly with
> "PST".

Yes, but, "*don’t change PHP time zone with `date_default_timezone_set()` (this one is **hard** requirement for correct core operation!)*" — https://make.wordpress.org/core/2019/09/23/date-time-improvements-wp-5-3/.

> I didn't think I needed to explicitly set the timezone since I already
> set it in WordPress

WordPress does use what you set there, but WordPress does not set it as the default (PHP) time zone.

WordPress uses it mainly when calculating dates and times (based on a [PHP timezone string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) or a ±HH:MM offset), and thus in order to get the *correct calculations*, WordPress sets the default time zone to UTC when WordPress loads (see [`wp-settings.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.8.3/src/wp-settings.php#L68), line 68).

---

So instead of overidding the default PHP time zone, you can use [`date_i18n()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/date_i18n/) to get the same "PST" like you said, i.e. the same date with the correct time zone based on your site's settings. E.g.

```php
$value_from_db = '2022-01-16 09:00:00'; // value hard-coded for testing

// If the site's time zone is America/Los_Angeles, this would output 1/16/22 @ 9:00AM PST
echo date_i18n( 'n/j/y @ g:iA T', strtotime( $value_from_db ) );

/* You'd see the exact same output as when using:
date_default_timezone_set( 'America/Los_Angeles' );
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $value_from_db );
echo $dt->format( 'n/j/y @ g:iA T' ); // 1/16/22 @ 9:00AM PST
*/
```

Or you can use [`wp_date()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_date/), but the documentation says, "*Note that, unlike `date_i18n()`, this function accepts a true Unix timestamp, not summed with timezone offset.*", which means if the GMT offset was -8 (8 hours behind GMT/UTC), then `wp_date()` would return a date that's 8 hours **less than** the date that's returned by `date_i18n()`.

```php
$value_from_db = '2022-01-16 09:00:00'; // value hard-coded for testing

// If the site's time zone is America/Los_Angeles, this would output 1/16/22 @ 1:00AM PST
echo wp_date( 'n/j/y @ g:iA T', strtotime( $value_from_db ) );
```

So you should use either `date_i18n()` or `wp_date()` depending on your specific requirements.

And you might also be interested in:

- [`wp_timezone()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_timezone/) — Retrieves the time zone from site settings as a *`DateTimeZone` object*, e.g. `wp_timezone()->getName()` might return `America/Los_Angeles`.
- [`wp_timezone_string()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_timezone_string/) — Retrieves the time zone from site settings as a *string*, e.g. `America/Los_Angeles` or `-08:00`.

Comment: This is such a great answer, thank you!

Comment: I just wanted to say that I constantly come back to this answer as a reference. It's so helpful! Thank you again.